# Powershell tasks from local machine to remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am performing below tasks on remote machine from a local machine:

- Creating/Deleting/Modifying some directory
- Copying some folder from local to remote machine
- Installing some .exe silently with noninteractive option
- Exectuing some batch files

I want to write a script in PowerShell. Novice to PowerShell. I have done some basic investigation of terms like "PowerShell Remoting" etc.

What are the things I need to look for? Related exmple for this will help, where should I look for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from [docs on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx):

> To run a single command on a remote computer, use the ComputerName parameter. To run a series of related commands that share data, use the New-PSSession cmdlet to create a PSSession (a persistent connection) on the remote computer, and then use the Session parameter of Invoke-Command to run the command in the PSSession. To run a command in a disconnected session, use the InDisconnectedSession parameter. To run a command in a background job, use the AsJob parameter.

So basically you should do something like:

```
$session = New-PSSession    
Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath <PathToScript>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good section on PowerShell remoting in the [Getting Started with PowerShell 3.0](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start) Virtual Academy class.  If you don't want to start there, read the [about_Remote](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847900.aspx) help topic, then move on to the other remoting help topics listed at the bottom.