# Automating File Moves using Power Shell

Tags: file, powershell, automation, move

How do you automate file moves using PS script (without scheduler). I would like to move the file from local to a network/drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell tasks from local machine to remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988661/powershell-tasks-from-local-machine-to-remote-machine)

Comment: Use the Move-Item CMDLet.

Comment: "*automate .. (without scheduler)*" - you find another automation tool of your choice. Product recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow as they tend to invite spammers answering with adverts, and go out of date quickly making answers less useful for future people.

Answer (score 0):

Move-Item should do what you're asking:

```
Move-Item -Path PathToFile -Destination DestinationPath
```

Comment: But how do you schedule that to happen, say, every day at 3 PM?